# visio event for layer name change, new layer and so on

Tags: c#, events, layer, visio

i am programming a little layer manager  as add-on (or add-in?) for visio in c#. Therefore i need an event after name change of a layer or after creating a new layer without my layer manager. The rest is already done. But, I do not have any idea how to start.

How to get the layer events (name change, new layer, deleted layer, rename layer, ...)?

Thanks
Heiko

Answer (score 0):

The layer related events are cell-changed-events of the responding page. So you can set an event to the ActivePage.CellChanged.

When the event is active, you can check the cell that was changed to get only layer related events. I did it by checking cell.LocalName.StartsWith("Layer.").